# Gap appearing between 2 divs when zooming in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header, followed by a title-picture (Means 100% width and a little welcome text-overlay) and that is followed by the main content space. My problem is between the title-pic and the main-content area, it looks normal on 100% zoom, but when zooming in, a gap with round about 75px appears on 150% zoom Level, where you see the background Image.
Do you know how to fix that or what cause those problems? I have normalize and clearfix in my css-file.

Comment: is there margin and padding

Comment: add a screenshot or code snippet